# Is there a way to set character encoding when reading sas files to spark or when pulling the data to the r session?

Tags: r, apache-spark, character-encoding

So, I have sas7bdat files that are huge and I would like to read them to spark, process them and then collect the results to a r session. I'm reading them to spark using the package `spark.sas7bdat` and function `spark_read_sas`. So far so good. The problem is that the character encoding of the sas7bdat files is iso-8859-1 but to show the content correctly in R it would need to be UTF-8. When I pull the results to R, my data looks like this. (Let's first create an example that has the same raw bytes that my results have)

```
mydf <- data.frame(myvar = rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xef, 0xbf, 0xbd, 0x62, 0x63))))

head(mydf$myvar,1) # should get äbc if it was originally read correctly
> �bc
```

Changing the encoding afterwards doesn't work for some reason.

```
iconv(head(mydf$myvar,1), from = 'iso-8859-1', to = 'UTF-8')
> ï¿½bc
```

If I use `haven` package and `read_sas('myfile.sas7bdat', encoding = 'iso-8859-1')` to read the file directly to my r-session, everything works as expected.

```
head(mydf$myvar,1)
> äbc
```

I would be very grateful for a solution that enables me to do the processing in spark and then collect only the results to R-session because the files are so big. I guess this could potentially either be solved when a) reading the file to spark (but I did not find and option that would work) or b) correcting the encoding in R (could not get it to work but do not understand why, maybe it could have something to do with special character encoding in the sas7bdat file).

Comment: According this table: http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/ISO-8859-1/list.htm, the `ä` character in `iso-8859-1` is represented by the single byte `e4`. It's pretty strange the raw content you got.

Comment: @nicola you are right. so it seems that the character encoding in the sas7bdat file is somehow special, on top of being 'iso-8859-1'. That or then reading it to spark further messes with the encoding